# iptablesの仕様について

Tags: iptables

/etc/sysconfig/iptablesに直接DROPしたIPアドレスのルールを記載して、
読み込みを実施すると一部のIPアドレスがドメイン名に変換されるのですが、
変換されないようにIPアドレスで登録する方法はあるのでしょうか(仕様なのかどうか)

※/etc/sysconfig/iptablesの一部の中身
-A INPUT -s 1.3.3.0/24 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 1.9.69.35/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 1.10.16.0/20 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 1.21.0.0/22 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 1.22.172.142/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 1.22.225.64/32 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 1.23.165.11/32 -j DROP

※iptables -Lで抽出したiptablesのリスト
DROP       all  --  1.3.3.0/24           anywhere
DROP       all  --  mail.bankpstn.com.my  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  1.10.16.0/20         anywhere            
DROP       all  --  1.21.0.0/22          anywhere            
DROP       all  --  1.22.172.142         anywhere            
DROP       all  --  1.22.225.64          anywhere            
DROP       all  --  mail.web-studioz.com  anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptablesは表示するときに名前解決をしているだけで、登録自体はIPアドレスで登録されています。

numericオプションを利用すれば名前解決しない形で表示することが可能です。

http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html

> -n, --numeric
>   Numeric output. IP addresses and port numbers will be printed in numeric format. By default, the program will try to display
>   them as host names, network names, or services (whenever applicable).

Comment: keitaro_soさん　ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

Comment: はじめてのご利用の方ですかね？是非、[質問に回答がついたら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考にして更に回答を求めるなどの行動をしてこのサイトに貢献していきましょう。